# Nothing survives reboot in Debian Jessie

Tags: debian, reboot

Running RasPBX based on Debian Jessie - I tried to change a few .conf files, but they always reverted following reboot. I initially thought this was dhcp messing with things, but it turns out nothing survives reboot. Even a .txt file I created in the home directory gets deleted.

tl;dr - SSH in, change stuff, reboot, all changes reverted.

Output of mount:

```
/dev/mmcblk0p2 on / type ext4 (rw,noatime,data=ordered)
devtmpfs on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,relatime,size=469688k,nr_inodes=117422,mode=755)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,mode=755)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,release_agent=/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-agent,name=systemd)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=22,pgrp=1,timeout=300,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,relatime)
configfs on /sys/kernel/config type configfs (rw,relatime)
/dev/mmcblk0p1 on /boot type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
```

Output of dmesg | grep -E 'mmc|ext' :)

```
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: 8250.nr_uarts=1 dma.dmachans=0x7f35 bcm2708_fb.fbwidth=656 bcm2708_fb.fbheight=416 bcm2709.boardrev=0xa02082 bcm2709.serial=0xb59dde09 smsc95xx.macaddr=B8:27:EB:9D:DE:09 bcm2708_fb.fbswap=1 bcm2709.uart_clock=48000000 vc_mem.mem_base=0x3dc00000 vc_mem.mem_size=0x3f000000  dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=ttyS0,115200 console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait
      .text : 0x80008000 - 0x807945f0   (7730 kB)
[    0.052137] CPU: Virtualization extensions available.
[    2.418638] mmc0: sdhost-bcm2835 loaded - DMA enabled (>1)
[    2.451228] mmc-bcm2835 3f300000.mmc: mmc_debug:0 mmc_debug2:0
[    2.462049] mmc-bcm2835 3f300000.mmc: DMA channel allocated
[    2.489744] mmc0: host does not support reading read-only switch, assuming write-enable
[    2.508346] mmc0: new high speed SDHC card at address 59b4
[    2.654165] Waiting for root device /dev/mmcblk0p2...
[    2.654367] mmcblk0: mmc0:59b4 00000 7.35 GiB
[    2.655651]  mmcblk0: p1 p2
[    2.674572] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (2 bytes)
[    2.676113] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (3 bytes)
[    2.677657] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (3 bytes)
[    2.680430] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (7 bytes)
[    2.742278] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): INFO: recovery required on readonly filesystem
[    2.755364] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): write access will be enabled during recovery
[    2.770294] mmc1: new high speed SDIO card at address 0001
[    2.932862] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): orphan cleanup on readonly fs
[    2.945051] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): 2 orphan inodes deleted
[    2.955001] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): recovery complete
[    2.971534] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    2.987156] VFS: Mounted root (ext4 filesystem) readonly on device 179:2.
[    4.532519] systemd[1]: Expecting device dev-mmcblk0p1.device...
[    6.365651] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): re-mounted. Opts: (null)
[    6.721847] FAT-fs (mmcblk0p1): Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be corrupt. Please run fsck.
[    7.736280] Adding 102396k swap on /var/swap.  Priority:-1 extents:7 across:307200k SSFS
```

Refuses to run fsck:

```
fsck from util-linux 2.25.2
e2fsck 1.42.12 (29-Aug-2014)
/dev/mmcblk0p2 is mounted.
e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting.
```

Also, refuses to unmount /dev/mmcblk0p2 - claiming target is busy.

Tried:

```
shutdown -F -r now
```

Resulting in:

```
Code should not be reached 'Unhandled option' at ../src/systemctl systemctl.c:6316, function shutdown_parse_argv(). Aborting.
Aborted
```

Comment: Have you actually installed it, or is this some "live" CD/USB or equivalent?

Comment: @derobert It is actually installed, insofar as raspi operating systems are - they always run from the SD card. This is a new problem, it only started doing this a few weeks after installation.

Comment: That is indeed odd... anything in `dmesg` (well, there will be a lot there—hundreds of lines—but any errors in there? Especially referring to mmcblk0? and/or ext4. `dmesg | grep -E 'mmc|ext'` might help)

Comment: @Alex also, another question—those things in dmesg said it wasn't shut down properly. Do the changes persist if you give it a proper shutdown (e.g., `shutdown -h now`)?

Comment: Nope, the changes don't persist with a proper shutdown.

Comment: There is also no grub menu

Comment: In ARM Linux we do not have grub. I do suggest buying a  PL2303HX USB to UART TTL Cable in amazon or Ali express for headless configurations.

Comment: Apparently on Raspberry Pi you edit [`/boot/cmdline.txt`](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/14839/how-to-change-the-kernel-commandline-for-archlinuxarm-on-raspberry-pi-effectly) ... that's on a different filesystem, so that write should work (and if it doesn't, I'd suspect you have a failed SD card).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same (reboots didn't stay - at reboot, always fsck). For me the reason was a dying SD card. Do you have the possibility to try dd'ing this card's contents to another card?